# Solidity Noob: Where can i see the return of a function?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am very new to Solidty, and I am very confused !
I have the sample following code:

```
contract HelloSystem {

    address owner;

    // Constructor
    function HelloSystem(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function remove() {
        if (msg.sender == owner){
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }
}

contract HelloFactory {

    function createHS() returns (address hsAddr) {
        return address(new HelloSystem());
    }

    function deleteHS(address hs){
        HelloSystem(hs).remove();
    }

}
```

It seems to compile fine with Remix but when I execute HelloFactory createHS, I got the output as the following:

```
Result: {
  "blockHash": "0x79a38504395749076aaad0b166eaee8b6f432dc7d880757b163d35ad6b8e17d1",
  "blockNumber": 25901,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 126668,
  "from": "0x6554c173718e20c84489ae563087787a5ebe2334",
  "gasUsed": 126668,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "root": "0x756e1a1139d2230556439930c7484de9cde3246e2e582e322e36c34e6c422eef",
  "to": "0xbbd6eebb731838296848b4983337e1a92f97cc89",
  "transactionHash": "0x8f3a32bf6520aa668eedfa1d68773cfd525bcfe21773aee81ccd50a2330cd2fd",
  "transactionIndex": 0
}
Transaction cost: 126668 gas.
```

Where is the actual address of my HelloSystem contract ?! I don't understand where is the actually returned data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added the `CreatedHS(...)` event and called this in `createHS()`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract HelloSystem {

    address owner;

    // Constructor
    function HelloSystem(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function remove() {
        if (msg.sender == owner){
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }
}

contract HelloFactory {
    event CreatedHS(address indexed hsAddr);

    function createHS() returns (address hsAddr) {
        HelloSystem hs = new HelloSystem();
        CreatedHS(hs);
        return hs;
    }

    function deleteHS(address hs){
        HelloSystem(hs).remove();
    }

}
```

The following screen shows the address result logged with the `CreatedHS(...)` event:

[image]

The returned data from calling `createHS()` will be a transaction hash. After your transaction is mined into a block, you can retrieve the transaction result using `eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)`, which is the output you listed in your question.

The easiest way to retrieve your newly created contract address is to log an event that includes this new address.